# Unicode character ſ (U+17F) in LyX 2.3

Tags: lyx, unicode, characters

How to use the following character ſ (U+17F) in LyX? Setting the UTF8 encoding does not work:

```
Package inputenc Error: Unicode character Ĺż (U+17F)
```

The complete source code of the document is:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
ſ
\end{document}
```

I have also tried to use:

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{17F}{ſ}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please check the site for "Package inputenc Error: Unicode character", there are quite a few occurences.

Comment: @ albert: May I kindly ask you for the clarification of your recommendation?  Thanks.

Comment: On the top of the page there is a  "Search on TeX - LaTeX..." give the text there or use Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First we have to find a way to insert the needed glyph.
The standard font Computer Modern does not include a ſ, so another font is needed.
A good alternative is Latin Modern, which should be mostly compatible with Computer Modern but features a significantly wider range of characters.
Latin Modern has `ſ` encoded in slot 115 (ASCII s) of the `TS1` encoding.

To make the `TS1` encoding available, replace

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

with

```
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
```

Then you have two options: Use Latin Modern for you entire document or only use one glyph from this font. If you want to use the complete font, add

```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{17F}{{%
  \fontencoding{TS1}%
  \selectfont s%
}}
```

To avoid changing the global font, you can instead add

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{17F}{{%
  \fontencoding{TS1}%
  \fontfamily{lmr}%
  \selectfont s%
}}
```

This tells LaTeX to use the `s` from encoding `TS1` (and family `lmr`), whenever Unicode character `U+017F` is requested.

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{17F}{{%
  \fontencoding{TS1}%
  \selectfont s%
}}
\begin{document}
ſ
\end{document}
```

A more elegant solution would be switching to LuaLaTeX, there you can directly use `ſ` as long as the character exists in your font.

Comment: @ Marcel: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation of the problem as well as for the proposed solution. It works well. Is there any other font supporting this unicode character?

Comment: @justik Without LuaTeX or XeTeX, you can not really speak about fonts supporting a unicode character, because they use completely different encodings than unicode. Anyway there probably are other fonts with this character, but I do not know them. You could try [DayRoman](https://ctan.org/pkg/dayroman). Also `kpfonts` includes the glyph but it is accessed in another way. See the [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/kpfonts/doc/kpfonts.pdf) for details.

Comment: @ Marcel: Thanks. I will try the recommended fonts...